# jQuery - setInterval issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery to generate and add a random amount of Clouds to the Header of the page and move them left on the specified interval. Everything is working fine, execpt the interval only runs once for each Cloud and not again. Here is my code:

```
if(enableClouds) {
    var cloudCount = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11); // Random Number between 1 & 10

    for(cnt = 0; cnt < cloudCount; cnt++) {
        var cloudNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
        var headerHeight = $('header').height() / 2;
        var cloudLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * docWidth);
        var cloudTop = 0;
        var thisHeight = 0;
        var cloudType = "one";

        if(cloudNumber == 2) {
            cloudType = "two";
        }else if(cloudNumber == 3) {
            cloudType = "three";
        }

        $('header').append('<div id="cloud' + cnt + '" class="cloud ' + cloudType + '"></div>');

        thisHeight = $('#cloud' + cnt).height();
        headerHeight -= thisHeight;
        cloudTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * headerHeight);

        $('#cloud' + cnt).css({
            'left' : cloudLeft,
            'top' : cloudTop
        });

        setInterval(moveCloud(cnt), 100);
    }

    function moveCloud(cloud) {
        var thisLeft = $('#cloud' + cloud).css('left');

        alert(thisLeft);
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way to go:

```
 setInterval((function(i){
      return function(){
         moveCloud(i);
      };
 })(cnt), 100);
```

Comment: For clarity, I'd suggest changing the internal `cnt`s to something else (so that it's clear which is which). But yeah: this is the way to go

Comment: @Dancrumb I think you are right, it is worth to think about `js newbie`s also ;).

Comment: @Engineer: Yeah, this is actually some pretty high level JS stuff... I added an explanation in my answer below, but +1 yours because it's dead on.

Answer (score 2):

Engineer gave you the code you need. Here's what's happening.

The `setInterval` function takes a Function object and an interval. A Function object is simply an object that you can call, like so:

```
/* Create it */
var func = function() { /* ... blah ... */};

/* Call it */
var returnVal =  func(parameters)
```

The object here is `func`. If you call it, what you get back is the return value.

So, in your code:

```
setInterval(moveCloud(cnt), 100);
```

you're feeding `setInterval` the return value of the call `moveCloud(cnt)`, instead of the the function object `moveCloud`. So that bit is broken.

An incorrect implementation would be:

```
for(cnt = 0; cnt < cloudCount; cnt++) {
    /* ... other stuff ... */
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
       moveCloud(cnt);
    }, 100);
}
```

Now, you're feeding it a function object, which is correct. When this function object is called, it's going to call `moveCloud`. The problem here is the `cnt`.

What you create here is a closure. You capture a reference to the variable `cnt`. When the function object that you passed to `setInterval` is called, it sees the reference to `cnt` and tries to resolve it. When it does this, it gets to the variable that you iterated over, looks at its value and discovers that it is equal to `cloudCount`. Problem is, does not map on to a Cloud that you created (you have clouds 0 to (cloudCount -1)), so at best, nothing happens, at worst, you get an error.

The right way to go is:

```
 setInterval((function(i){
      return function(){
         moveCloud(i);
      };
 })(cnt), 100);
```

This uses an 'immediate function' that returns a function. You create a function:

```
function(i){
    return function(){
        moveCloud(i);
    };
}
```

that returns another function (let's call it `outer`) which, when called with a value `i`, calls `moveCloud` with that value.
Then, we *immediately* call `outer` with our value `cnt`. What this gives us is a function which, when called, calls `moveCloud` with **whatever the value of `cnt` is at this point in time**. This is exactly what we want!

And that's why we do it that way.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it's really helped me understand setInterval more!